# How do I output a string containing quotation marks?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am not super computer literate. I am trying to use the equations to grade my Google quiz, the problem is that there is a quote in the answer. Is there a different symbol I need to use?

This is what I have right now:

```
=if(C2= "Aubrey said, "you are my favorite friend."", 10, 0)
```

The answer is Aubrey said, "you are my favorite friend."

I would just omit the quotes in the answer but it meant for an English quiz, so that may be sending the wrong message.

Answer (score 32):

You need to prepend your `"`s with another `"`:

```
=if(C2= "Aubrey said, ""you are my favorite friend.""", 10, 0)
```

Notice how you get *three* `"`s in a row - that's two `"`s to close the citation, and the last one to end the text string.

Answer (score 10):

Here is another way to do it in Google Sheets:

If A1 = `Hello" World`

Then you can compare to it using `=IF(A1 = CONCATENATE("Hello",char(34)," World"),TRUE,FALSE)`

That way you are using char(34) to substitute for " and CONCATENATE() to combine it into a single string.

Answer (score 0):

Remark on this solution:

```
=IF(A1 = CONCATENATE("Hello",char(34)," World"),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Please be noticed that you have " CHAR(34) and ״ CHAR(1524)

You can find your code by adding your needed char to the beginning of a string:
e.g. let say you want to find ״ code then create in a separate cell [e.g. B2] the string ״aaa (the ״ is the first char and the rest is to verify that Google figures out this cell content as a string type) than in another cell use this formula to convert the first char into Unicode index `=UNICODE(B2)`. As a result, you will get 1524
then you can use it:

```
=IF(A1 = CONCATENATE("Hello",char(1524)," World"),TRUE,FALSE)
```