# How can I stop apostrophes in names from tripping up formulae?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, special-characters

I'm using a formula to run through a list of names, compare them to a master list and check associated values for the names that appear on both.

```
=COUNTA( Iferror(QUERY(Requirements!A2:F, "select A where A matches '" & JOIN("|", Attendance!A2:A) & "' and B = 'Yes'", 0),))
```

However, some of the names contain apostrophes (eg. `O'Malley`) and this is killing the formula - Is there a simple way to escape or replace the apostrophe in the name either in the original lists or as the formula reads it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Google's Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#literals), string literals should be

> enclosed in either single or double quotes. Examples: "fourteen" 'hello world' "It's raining".

You are joining the Attendance values by `|` only, which again is enclosed in `'`s, so if `Attendance!A2:A` was

```
Larsson
O'Malley
Taylor
```

the result of the `"... '" & JOIN("|", Attendance!A2:A) & "' ..."` would be `'Larsson|O'Malley|Taylor'`.

As you can see, this leads to unmatched `'` - the string seemingly ends and begins with a `'`, but the apostrophe in `O'Malley` shortcuts the string so that it is really `'Larsson|O'`.

You could use `""` instead of `'` when creating the string:

```
=COUNTA( Iferror(QUERY(Requirements!A2:F, "select A where A matches """ & JOIN("|", Attendance!A2:A) & """ and B = 'Yes'", 0)))
```

Note how the [double quotation mark `""` allows the character to be escaped](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58018/21583), so it does not short-circuit the string.

This would allow `O'Malley` to be counted, but would be trouble if you have a name that includes `"`. To avoid all sorts of character issues, your formula should be rewritten so that it does not rely on creating a query by concatenating input strings.